# testing updating a record in a request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to update a record in a request spec, but it's not updating. Doing it in real life works. Here is the spec:

```
describe "sessions" do
  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @api_key = FactoryGirl.create(:api_key)
  end

  it "is updated properly" do
    put "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}?user_email=#{@user.email}&auth_token=#{@user.authentication_token}", {user: {name: "New Name"}},{ "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"=>"Token token=\"#{@api_key.access_token}\"" }
    @user.name.should eq("New Name")
    response.status.should be(201)
  end
end
```

The above test fails with the error:

```
Failure/Error: @user.name.should eq("New Name")

       expected: "New Name"
            got: "nil"

       (compared using ==)
```

Name is an optional parameter, so I just don't set it in the Factory. If I do set it the line says `got: "Bill"` for example.

and, for completeness, here are the factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "test#{n}@vitogo.com"
  end

      factory :user do
        email           
        password                            '12345678'
        password_confirmation '12345678'
        goal_id                             1
        experience_level_id     1
        gender                              'Female'
        factory :admin do
            after(:create) { |user| user.role = 'admin'; user.save }
        end
      end
    end

    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :api_key do
        access_token "MyString"
      end
    end
```

Comment: It is very likely that error is usually when you are not comparing the same thing. I.e If you compare an object with an array you will get this error. Or if you compare an array with an object you will get this error. If it is an object you are comparing against it needs to be `obj <-> obj` if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reload `@user` after your PUT call, e.g. `@user.reload`.

Comment: If your route accepts POST, and it does everything else the same way, it should work fine. But if your routes are set up with the standard `resources` then the POST might be routed to a create action rather than an update. Try logging `User.all` afterwards to see.

Comment: I love it when a wild guess comes together :)